# Google Maps InfoWindow has horizontal scroll bar

Tags: google-maps-api-3, infowindow

I have an issue with horizontal scroll bars appearing on the infoWindow popup when there is a lot of content inside.  It is fine when there is a small amount of content that doesn't go below the height.  However it seems to calculate the size before knowing the content goes below the height, so doesn't factor the scroll bar width in.

I have set the width of the containing div I'm passing it to 480px, but it is getting inserted into a div with only 460px, hence the scroll bar.  I've tried width auto as well.
I haven't managed to find a solution from answers to other similar questions I've read.

I have created a JSFiddle to show what I'm talking about:
http://jsfiddle.net/TH7yt/1/

Having the vertical scroll bar is acceptable, but I don't want the horizontal one.

Hopefully someone will be able to help me figure out how to get rid of it.

Thanks.

For those who want to see the code here:

HTML

```
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

CSS

```
#map-canvas {
    width: 1017px;
    height: 500px;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
.branch-location {
    width: 480px;
    padding-top:10px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.branch-location .block-title
{
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
.branch-location .contact-info
{
    width: 270px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Arial;
}
[class*="span"]
{
    float: left;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
.branch-location .contact-info address
{
    font-size: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-style: normal;
    line-height: 1.667em;
}
.branch-location .contact-info address .country
{
    display: block;
}
.branch-location .entry-link
{
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    color: #007571;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.branch-location .branch-note, .branch-location .branch-hours
{
    line-height: 1.667em;
}
.branch-location .branch-hours-heading
{
    display: block;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 8px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.branch-location .contact-entries-block
{
    float: left;
    line-height: 1.667em;
    margin-left: 30px;
    width: 160px;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
.branch-location .contact-entries-block a
{
    display: block;
    color: #007571;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.numbers .tel-numbers
{
    display: block;
    margin-left: 13px;
}
```

Javascript

```
var lat = -37.7833;
var lng = 144.9667;
var coord = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
var infoHTML = '<div class="row branch-location" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">' +
    '<h3 class="block-title" itemprop="name"></span>Test Branch</h3>' +
    '<div class="span3 contact-info">' +
    '<address itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">' +
    '<span itemprop="streetAddress">' +
    'Address Line1<br />' +
    'Address Line2<br />' +
    '</span>' +
    '<span itemprop="addressLocality">Suburb &nbsp</span> <span itemprop="addressRegion">State &nbsp</span><span itemprop="postalCode">Postcode</span><br />' +
    '<span itemprop="addressCountry" class="country">Australia</span></address>' +
    '<a href="http://maps.google.com?daddr=-37.7833,144.9667"' +
    'class="entry-link email-link" target="_blank">' +
    '<span class="icon icon-right-small"></span>' +
    'Get Directions' +
    '</a>' +
    '<span class="branch-note">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque enim lorem, semper at facilisis sit amet, convallis non massa. Etiam in mattis justo. Cras dictum rutrum elit, sed consequat eros facilisis adipiscing. Suspendisse id tincidunt dolor. Donec laoreet malesuada dolor, quis aliquam dolor eleifend pharetra. Integer id ipsum non nibh dapibus consequat ut vitae erat. Maecenas quis nisl odio, quis scelerisque mauris. Nullam sit amet nibh tellus, eu tempus urna. Quisque ut lectus sapien, a commodo urna.</span><span class="branch-hours-heading">Hours of Operation:</span>' +
    '<span class="branch-hours">8.30 AM to 5.30 PM</span>' +
    '</div>' +
    '<div class="contact-entries-block">' +
    '<div class="numbers">' +
    '<p itemprop="telephone">T 123456789<span class="tel-numbers">987654321</span></p>' +
    '<p itemprop="faxNumber">F 123456789</p>' +
    '</div>' +
    '<a href="mailto:test@someemail.com" title="" itemprop="email">test@someemail.com</a>' +
    '<a href="mailto:thisisalongemailtotestwrapping@someemail.com" title="" itemprop="email">thisisalongemailtotestwrapping@email.com</a>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>';

var mapOptions = {
    center: coord,
    zoom: 15,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
};

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: coord,
    map: map
});

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: infoHTML,
    position: coord
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
});

// Close infoWindow when user clicks anywhere on the map
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function () {
    infowindow.open(null, null);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

On my ubuntu chrome, I have no horizontal scrollbar untill I scroll down the end of text inside your infowindow. At this point, an horizontal scrollbar appears.

Just add

`.gm-style-iw div { 
 overflow:hidden !important; 
}`

inside your css to get rid of it